# Open a non-static method from one form on the close of another one

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I wanna know if it is possible to call a non-static function from e.g. Form1 on Form2 close event.

Here is where I open the second form:

```
 private void listaclientes_listbox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EditarCliente ed = new EditarCliente(listaclientes_listbox.SelectedIndex, bib);
        ed.Show();
    }
```

And this is the method I wanna call, which bellongs to the first form:

```
private void loadlista_clientes()
{
    listaclientes_listbox.Items.Clear();
    for (int p = 0; p < bib.index; p++)
        listaclientes_listbox.Items.Add(bib.ListaCliente[p].nome + " - CC: " + bib.ListaCliente[p].cc);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to add a handler for the FormClosed event (not sure if you are using [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closed(v=vs.110).aspx) or [WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

So something like this

```
private void listaclientes_listbox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EditarCliente ed = new EditarCliente(listaclientes_listbox.SelectedIndex, bib);
    ed.Closed += (o,e) => { loadlista_clientes(); }
    ed.Show();
}
```

Comment: I'm using WinForms. Sorry, I forgot that. I've updated the main post.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working. I would upvote you but, still not enough reputation. Again, thanks.